# Failing to build eleventy blog

Tags: javascript, eleventy

I am trying to create a personal blog. My directory structure looks like the following:

[image]

My `.eleventy.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.setTemplateFormats(["md", "html"]);

    // Copy static files to output folder
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('src/images');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('src/css');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('src/js');

    // Set input and output folders
    return {
        dir: {
            input: '_src',
            output: '_site',
            includes: '_includes',
            layouts: '_layouts'
        }
    };
};
```

When I build I get the following:

```
$ sudo npm run build

> personal_blog_eleventy@1.0.0 build
> eleventy

[11ty] Writing _site/_posts/post-1/index.html from ./_src/_posts/post-1.md (liquid)
[11ty] Writing _site/_posts/post-2/index.html from ./_src/_posts/post-2.md (liquid)
[11ty] Wrote 2 files in 0.11 seconds (v2.0.1)
```

However, when running `eleventy --serve` I only get:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a root `index.html` file, so the server is correct in saying it cannot GET the route `/`.

You can confirm by going to `http://localhost:8080/_posts/post-1` as that file does exist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What should I put into the index.html file?

Comment: Whatever you want, but probably a list of links to the other pages to start off.